# Define multiple sources/collection in a datasource in Eve

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

Is it possible in Eve to get data from multiple sources/collection to be define in one datasource and used by one endpoint.
The usual endpoint definition looks like this:

```
endpoint = {
  'item_title': 'title',
  'resource_methods': ['GET'],
  'datasource': {'source': 'collection1',
             'default_sort': [('time', -1)]},
  'schema': schema
}
```

Is it possible to include documents from more than one collection for the same endpoint by making changes at 'Domain' or 'endpoint' tag?

Comment: You could use a flask custom endpoint to manipulate your data, and then register it in eve app. See here (https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/snippets/hooks_blueprints.html). You could build a blueprint like that from the example.

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope, we instead created a merged collection as source. It's not supported by Eve, alternative is what @gcw mentioned.